# Clojure: recur vs. recursion via fn name

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm just a beginner on Clojure, and I've been trying the 4clojure.com problems. There I stumbled upon a problem in an exercise where I am supposed to write a `flatten` implementation.

I *basically* understand the concept of tail call optimization, and how `recur` allows not consuming the stack, as opposed to "normal" recursion (I don't know if there's a proper term).

And that's why I don't get what is going on here:

```
(defn foo1 [x]
  (if (> x 0)
    (do (println x)
        (foo1 (dec x)))))

(defn foo2 [x]
  (if (> x 0)
    (do (println x)
        (recur (dec x)))))
```

As expected both `foo1` and `foo2` are the same functionally, but, given a parameter large enough (100000 in my case), I get a stack overflow™ on `foo1` while `foo2` completes normally.

Now, on to the `flatten` problem:

```
(defn flatten1 [ls]
  (mapcat
    #(if (coll? %)
      (flatten1 %)
      (list %))
    ls))

(defn flatten2 [ls]
  (mapcat
    #(if (coll? %)
      (recur %)
      (list %))
    ls))
```

Test case:

```
(flatten [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]])
(flatten1 [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]])
(flatten2 [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]])
```

Expected result: `'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)`

Well, `flatten1` works ok (it's a small input anyway). But `flatten2` just hangs indefinitely. Doesn't `recur` target the recursion point set at the `defn`? What's the difference (optimization aside) with recursing to the function by name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By modifying the program a bit you can see the problem:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] )
  (:gen-class))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn flatten1 [ls]
  (mapcat
    (fn [it]
      (println "f1: it=" it)
      (if (coll? it)
        (flatten1 it)
        (list it)))
    ls))

(defn flatten2 [ls]
  (mapcat
    (fn [it]
      (println "f2: it=" it)
      (if (coll? it)
        (recur it)
        (list it)))
    ls))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (newline) (println "main - 1")
  (spyx (flatten  [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]]))

  (newline) (println "main - 2")
  (spyx (flatten1 [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]]))

  (newline) (println "main - 3")
  (flatten2 [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]])
```

Running the code produces this output:

```
main - 1
(flatten [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]]) => (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)

main - 2
f1: it= 1
f1: it= [2]
f1: it= 2
f1: it= 3
f1: it= [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]
f1: it= 4
f1: it= [5 6 [7] 8]
f1: it= 5
f1: it= 6
f1: it= [7]
f1: it= 7
f1: it= 8
(flatten1 [1 [2] 3 [4 [5 6 [7] 8]]]) => (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)

main - 3
f2: it= 1
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
f2: it= [2]
```

So you can see it gets stuck on the `[2]` item, the 2nd element of the input list.

The reason this fails is that the `recur` statement only jumps back to the innermost function, which is the anonymous form `#(if ...)` in your original problem, of the form `(fn [it] ...)` in the 2nd version.

Note that `recur` can only "jump" to the innermost fn/loop target. You cannot use `recur` to jump out of your inner anonymous function to reach `flatten2`.  Since it only jumps to the inner function, the 1-elem collection `[2]` does not replace the `ls` value at the end of the `mapcat` call, and you therefore get the infinite loop.

The best advice for any programming is "keep it simple". Recursion is simpler than loop/recur for most problems.

On the JVM, each stack frame requires some memory (consult the docs about the `-Xs` switch to increase). If you use too many stack frames, you will eventually run out of memory (controlled by the `-Xmx` switch). You should usually be able to count on at least 1000 stack frames being available (you can test if you like for your machine & params). So as a rule of thumb, if your recursion depth is 1000 or less, don't worry about using `loop/recur`.

Comment: To deal with this problem, there is a proposal, extant though dormant, to enable [recur to named loops](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Named+loops+with+recur-to).